# How to identify cluster through unsupervised training

Tags: matlab

I have  a sensor data and i want to identify clusters using unsupervised  training. which algorithm  would be best. I have read here that self organizing Map (SOM) is not a cluster identification tool rather dimension reduction tool .Matlab has bulit in SOM tool but its hard to interpret , is there any other good tool available for SOM

Comment: We really need more context. What kind of "cluster" are you referring to? What kind of input data are you expecting? Are you attempting to identify point-clusters in n-dimensional space (where n>=2)?

Comment: Actually I do nt have high dimension i have data for a sensor measuring voltage on every second in 24 hours, i have seen in Excel that there are several peaks visible, i am thinking to find cluster having almost same values.